# TypeScript: Array.reduce Function in VS Code reports error

Tags: javascript, typescript, webstorm

TypeScript: `Array.reduce` Function in VS Code reports error but in WebStorm is normal.

This is the present in VS Code:

[image: VS Code]

It reports

> Type String is not assigned to the Type String[]

And this is the present in WebStorm:

[image: WebStorm]

Although there is not a problem, the callback annotation is not presented, like `map` and `filter` above

The previous code is:

```
 private getUrlParameter(sParam) {
    return decodeURIComponent(window.location.search.substring(1)).split('&')
      .map((v) => v.split('='))
      .filter((v) => v[0] === sParam )
      .reduce((prev, curv, index, array) => curv[1], undefined);
  }
```

I don't know whether the problem is in my code  or the TypeScript's compiler.

Comment: If you ignore the warning, does the code run as expected?

Comment: @Baksteen Yes, it runs well in my Angular 5's Component, I just feel stranged.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `undefined` the selected overload will be

```
reduce(callbackfn: (previousValue: T, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => T, initialValue: T): T;
```

Which expects the result to be the same type as an item of the array.

You should use a type assertion on the initial value (`undefined`) to let the compiler know the result type will be `string`  or specify the type argument for `reduce`

```
.reduce((prev, curv, index, array) => curv[1], <string>undefined);
.reduce<string>((prev, curv, index, array) => curv[1], undefined)
```

If you do that the selected overload will be

```
reduce<U>(callbackfn: (previousValue: U, currentValue: T, currentIndex: number, array: T[]) => U, initialValue: U): U;
```

Comment: It helps, thanks a lot ! 
But the webStorm's callbackFn anotation is still hiding, unless I delete the 'initialValue'. 
However It doesn't matter anything now, I figure it may be the webStorm's

Comment: I think the correct type for the initial item is `undefined as string | undefined`